# How do I start to debug “recipe for target 'all' failed” When compiling a C ++ Library

Tags: c++, mingw-w64

Any tips on where I can start bugging this would be great.
I'm not sure where to start

[I'm building this Library Unmodified  using CMake and MinGW,](https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/fitsio/CCfits/)
I'm getting a series of warnings about deprecated code being used but as I haven't developed this code I don't know about modifying it to remove those, and since they're warnings not errors I'm not sure if this is necessary.

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\ccfits3\CCfits\FITS.cxx: In constructor 'CCfits::FITS::FITS(const String&, CCfits::RWmode, bool, const std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >&)':
C:\Users\user\Desktop\ccfits3\CCfits\FITS.cxx:91:11: warning: 'template<class> class std::auto_ptr' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      std::auto_ptr<FITSBase> apBase(new FITSBase(name,mode));
           ^~~~~~~~
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\locale_conv.h:41:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\locale:43,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\iomanip:43,
                 from C:\Users\user\Desktop\ccfits3\CCfits\KeyData.h:20,
                 from C:\Users\user\Desktop\ccfits3\CCfits\KeywordCreator.h:13,
                 from C:\Users\user\Desktop\ccfits3\CCfits\NewKeyword.h:13,
                 from C:\Users\user\Desktop\ccfits3\CCfits\HDU.h:21,
                 from C:\Users\user\Desktop\ccfits3\CCfits\ExtHDU.h:15,
                 from C:\Users\user\Desktop\ccfits3\CCfits\Table.h:13,
                 from C:\Users\user\Desktop\ccfits3\CCfits\FITS.cxx:10:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\unique_ptr.h:49:28: note: declared here
   template<typename> class auto_ptr;
                            ^~~~~~~~
C:\Users\user\Desktop\ccfits3\CCfits\FITS.cxx: In constructor 'CCfits::FITS::FITS(const String&, CCfits::RWmode, const string&, bool, const std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >&, const std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >&, int)':
C:\Users\user\Desktop\ccfits3\CCfits\FITS.cxx:147:16: warning: 'template<class> class std::auto_ptr' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
           std::auto_ptr<FITSBase> apBase(new FITSBase(name,mode));
                ^~~~~~~~
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\locale_conv.h:41:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\locale:43,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\iomanip:43,
                 from C:\Users\user\Desktop\ccfits3\CCfits\KeyData.h:20,
                 from C:\Users\user\Desktop\ccfits3\CCfits\KeywordCreator.h:13,
                 from C:\Users\user\Desktop\ccfits3\CCfits\NewKeyword.h:13,
                 from C:\Users\user\Desktop\ccfits3\CCfits\HDU.h:21,
                 from C:\Users\user\Desktop\ccfits3\CCfits\ExtHDU.h:15,
                 from C:\Users\user\Desktop\ccfits3\CCfits\Table.h:13,
                 from C:\Users\user\Desktop\ccfits3\CCfits\FITS.cxx:10:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\unique_ptr.h:49:28: note: declared here
   template<typename> class auto_ptr;
                            ^~~~~~~~
```

at the end of the build process, I get the error

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2020.2.4\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" --build 
C:\Users\user\Desktop\cfits2\CCfits\debug --target all -- -j 3
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [libCCfits.a] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/CCfits.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [all] Error 2
CMakeFiles\CCfits.dir\build.make:375: recipe for target 'libCCfits.a' failed
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:96: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/CCfits.dir/all' failed
Makefile:159: recipe for target 'all' failed
```

I don't know where to go from here what's my next step in the still bugging process.
the error really doesn't seem to tell me anything useful,  and the warnings are probably unrelated I think.
I don't think I can get rid of the warnings without a deeper understanding of the library.
thank you please forgive the stupid question

Comment: `std::auto_ptr` has been made obsolete c++11 and removed in c++17 and use  `std::unique_ptr` instead. related: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/auto_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/auto_ptr)

Comment: One of these is an error, not a warning, which is why that libCCfits.a fails to be built.